# how use conditions in sub query Cakephp while using contain behaviour

Tags: sql, cakephp, subquery, contain

i'm trying to access only those cities where country id = 2 and city id = 5

```
$this->Country->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Country.id' => 2),
        'contain' => array(
          'City' => array(
            'conditions' => array('City.id' => 5)))));
```

I tried this to get city with id 5 but all cities are listed where country id is 2.

I know this is not good approach to get cities using this query . 
I can use

```
$this->City->findById('5');
$this->City->find('all', 
           array('conditions' => array('id' => 5 , 'country_id' => 2)));
```

But I want to know if I wanna use above way then how it can be used in proper way because some where else it can be used in future.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [JOINs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

When you use contain in the 1st example, you can basically think of it like two queries (which is what it runs most of the time using Containable):

```
1) get all Countries of id 2
2) get all Cities of id 5
```

(Notice how it's NOT joining them together - it does two completely separate queries, then just puts them both into an array)

Instead, use INNER JOIN to create a single query where it only returns the results that match both conditions.

Comment: can you help me to write inner join query for this situation

Comment: If you post another question with your attempts at writing a join, I'd be happy to help point out where you're off..etc.

Comment: i have posted another question, kindly check it here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092064/how-use-multiple-conditions-to-get-data-from-2-habtm-tables-in-cakephp-2-x