# how use multiple conditions to get data from 2 HABTM tables in Cakephp 2.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to get only those products which have specific brand and category.

in Product model i used this query

```
$products = $this->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
             array('table' => 'brands_products',
                'alias' => 'BrandsProducts',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'BrandsProducts.brand_id' => $brandId,
                    'BrandsProducts.product_id = Product.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'group' => 'Product.id'
    ));
```

By using above query i can get only those products which has specific brand id.

Exactly i don't know how to use multiple conditions to get data from 2 HABTM tables.
in my example product HABTM relation with Category and Brands.

```
$products = $this->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
             array('table' => 'brands_products',
                'alias' => 'BrandsProducts',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'BrandsProducts.brand_id' => $brandId,
                    'BrandsProducts.product_id = Product.id'
                )
            ),
             array('table' => 'categories_products',
                'alias' => 'CategoriesProducts',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'CategoriesProducts.category_id' => $categoriesId,
                    'CategoriesProducts.product_id = Product.id'
                )
            )

        ),
        'group' => 'Product.id'
    ));
```

By using this query i got error in db. SO i'm looking how to write proper query to get only those products where brand and category match.

Comment: Put the exact error message in your question.

Comment: Have a look http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: i found solution thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please write your solution as and answer here so others can benefit from it also?